# Unable to get checkboxes values in codeigniter-3

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox, codeigniter-3

I am using codeigniter 3.16 on an Ubuntu 14.04 server, with apache 2.6 and php 5.6. I have created a multipart form to upload several files and check (or not) a group of checkboxes. My view looks something like:

```
<form id="creation_form" name="creation_form" class="form-horizontal" action="<?=(isset($edit)?site_url('admin/Projects/edit/').$project->ID:site_url('admin/Projects/create'))?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
// ...
    <?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?>
    <tr>
       <td><input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="<?= $user->ID ?>" <?=(isset($edit) && isset($project_users[$user->ID])?"checked":"")?>/></td>
       <td><?= $user->name ?></td>
       <td><?= $user->surname ?></td>
       <td><?= $user->email ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</form>
```

My controller gets the values of the checked checkboxes with this code:

```
$users_ids = $this->input->post("users");
if (!isset($users_ids) || sizeof($users_ids) == 0) {
    $error_msg = "Assign at least one user to the project";
}
```

But it is returning nothing, `$users_ids` is empty no matters how many checkboxes I check, and I am recovering other inputs like texts and files correctly but not the checkboxes.

Comment: Have you tried var_dump($this->input->post());exit; just before $user_ids to see what is actually being sent? Im not sure but I think the way multipart forms get sent may be slightly different. It doesnt look like you need multi/part forms for this form. With CI you can write echo form_open('controller/method','class="form-horizontal")

Comment: multipart forms are no different than regular forms except they have boundries for files. the post/get is the same. but yea probably not needed here if you aren't upload files.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I found what was happening. The files sizes that I was uploading in the form were exceeding the limit of post_max_size and upload_max_filesize parameters and that was the reason why  `input->post('xxxx')` was returning nothing.